# Warning: file_put_contents : failed to open stream: No such file or directory in php

Tags: php

```
<?PHP

class couty{
   public function write ($a,$b){

       @session_start();
       if(!(isset($_SESSION[`login`]) && $_SESSION[`login`] != ``)){
         echo "you must Logged in to create a PHP file";
       }
       else{
            file_put_contents($a,$b);
            exit;
       }
}
}

$c = `<!DOCTYPE HTML><HTML>
<head><title></title></head>
<body></body>
</HTML>`;

if($_SERVER[`REQUEST_METHOD`] == `POST`){
   $new = trim($_POST[`coutyv`]);
   $dir = (mkdir(`folder/$new`));
   $d = new couty();
   $d->write(`$dir/$new.php`,$c);
}
?>
<form method = `post` action = ``>
<input type = `text` name = `coutyv`/>
<input type = `submit` name = `submit`/>
</form>
```

Comment: your code is crappy, consider of rewrite the script

Comment: The error message pretty much says it all ?

Comment: Why are all your quotes like this `? They should be like this '. Also, your code have a lot of issues. Start by inspecting the individual lines of it to see if they work.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in here . Check if you have these folders or not. anyway your code is not good

```
  $dir = (mkdir(`folder/$new`));
   $d = new couty();
   $d->write(`$dir/$new.php`,$c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things I would do

1. Rename your variables from $d, $a, $c to meaningful names - >
   $new_directory, $output_filename, etc
2. Check that $new is infact a valid name.
3. Check that mkdir creates the directory successfully.
4. Add error handling for all situations in which it fails.

Could be, or might happen in the future:

```
$dir = (mkdir(`folder/$new`));  <--- $new might be bad / folder might be bad / call might fail
$d->write(`$dir/$new.php`,$c);  <--- maybe the $dir/$new.php generated a bad path.

// future potential errors:
$new = trim($_POST[`coutyv`]); <---- new might not exist, might be invalid, contain invalid
```

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507